How to get collection association info on the storefront
Problem statement: I'm looking for ways to get collection info on the storefront. The collection info in the context is the collections that a product variant is associated with. Say for example:
"Product variant A" is associated with "Collection A", "Collection B", etc.
Then on the storefront I want to access the data to confirm if the "Product variant A" is associated with "Collection X" or not.
Currently: I'm hitting my own server for getting that info.
Preferred solution: Can I use some sort of liquid file powers to get that info ? Also I cannot use token from storefront for obvious reasons. Therefore admin APIs goes out the window
I've looked into storefront APIs like product.json. But these don't carry collection info in there.
